# Access Session object at Session_End Event in Globle.asax file

Tags: asp.net

I want to access session variable at Session_End event of globle.asax file.But HtppContext.Current returns null. Please suggest any other way.

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                HttpContext ht = HttpContext.Current;

                string username = ht.Session["UserName"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: As the name of the event _Session End_ itself suggest it occurs when a session ends, so you can't access any session variable here. What you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to get current user UserName.

Comment: In _Session End_ event? Why so? Where you are setting the UserName? Where you want to display it?

Comment: I think the idea with Session_End is that it fires not within the context on an HTTP request, which is why HttpContext is null, and probably will be in every instance.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem yesterday, and I simply use:

```
string username = Session["UserName"].ToString();
```